# Seq Function Erroring Out w/ Multiple Rows in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to generate rows of sequences, within a function, for each row in my dataset. The problem I'm running into is that the `seq` function errors out because I have multiple rows. I've included an example dataset and my code (sequence call is third from bottom of my function).

```
df<-data.frame(
  'Acct'=c("A","B","A"),
  'Rate'=c(8,8,12),
  'Amount'=c(1000,1000,1500),
  'Freq'=c(2,2,2),
  'MtM'=c(6,6,12),
  'YtM2'=c(.10,.10,.05),
  'periods'=c(12,12,24),
  'Price'=c(911.54,911.54,1050.37),
  'Date'=c('Sep 2021','Sep 2021', 'May 2021')
)

 dur <- function(Rate, periods,YtM2, Price ,MtM,Amount) {
  i <- 1:periods
  cf <- c(rep(Rate, periods - 1), Amount + Rate)
  pv <- (cf / (1 + YtM2) ^ i)
  weight<-pv/Price
  seqi<-seq(MtM/periods,MtM,length.out=periods)
  endResults<-sum(seqi*weight)
  return(seqi) 
  }
  
  dur(df$Rate,df$periods,df$YtM2,df$Price,df$MtM,df$Amount)
```

When I run the code I get an error:

```
Error in seq.default(MtM/periods, MtM, length.out = periods) : 
  'from' must be of length 1
```

Ideally, I would just store these sequences temporarily. I'm trying to experiment by using `dplyr::group_by` statement where I group by `Acct` and `Date` and then generate the sequence ie `seqi<-df%>%group_by(Acct,Date)%>%seq(MtM/df$periods,df$MtM, length.out=df$periods)` but I just get this error

`Error in seq.default(., MtM/df$periods, df$MtM, length.out = df$periods) :  'from' must be of length 1 In addition: Warning message: In seq.default(., MtM/df$periods, df$MtM, length.out = df$periods) : first element used of 'length.out' argument`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to apply `dur` function for each row, you can use any of the apply function.

For example, with `Map`.

```
with(df, Map(dur, Rate, periods,YtM2, Price ,MtM,Amount))

#[[1]]
# [1] 0.5 1.0 1.5 2.0 2.5 3.0 3.5 4.0 4.5 5.0 5.5 6.0

#[[2]]
# [1] 0.5 1.0 1.5 2.0 2.5 3.0 3.5 4.0 4.5 5.0 5.5 6.0

#[[3]]
# [1]  0.5  1.0  1.5  2.0  2.5  3.0  3.5  4.0  4.5  5.0  5.5  6.0  6.5
#[14]  7.0  7.5  8.0  8.5  9.0  9.5 10.0 10.5 11.0 11.5 12.0
```

I removed the last `Price` argument from the function since it was repeated twice.

Answer (score 0):

We may use `do.call` with `Map` after subsetting the columns with the order of the input arguments in 'dur'

```
 do.call(Map, c(f = dur, unname(df[c(2, 7, 6, 8, 5, 3)])))
[[1]]
 [1] 0.5 1.0 1.5 2.0 2.5 3.0 3.5 4.0 4.5 5.0 5.5 6.0

[[2]]
 [1] 0.5 1.0 1.5 2.0 2.5 3.0 3.5 4.0 4.5 5.0 5.5 6.0

[[3]]
 [1]  0.5  1.0  1.5  2.0  2.5  3.0  3.5  4.0  4.5  5.0  5.5  6.0  6.5  7.0  7.5  8.0  8.5  9.0  9.5 10.0 10.5 11.0 11.5 12.0
```